# The meaning of 'congressmen have principle' in the context

Tags: meaning

This is the part from a novel 'Baker's blue-jay yarn' by Mark Twain. 
The sentence in bold is what I don't exactly understand.

> *You may call a jay a bird. Well, so he is, in a measure - because he's got feathers on him, and don't belong to no church, perhaps; but otherwise he is just as much a human as you be. And I'll tell you for why. A jay's gifts, and instincts, and feelings and interests, cover the whole ground.* **A jay hasn't got any more principle than a congressman.** *A jay will lie, a jay will steal, a jay will deceive, a jay will betray; and four times out of five, a jay will go back on his solemnest promise.*

Does that sentence literally mean that congressmen normally have a lot of principles to follow while blue-jay doesn't have many of them? 
Or is there any connotative meaning?

Comment: No, it means a jaybird has *no more principles (=ethics)* than a congressman. It's a joke setting up congressmen as the standard, the benchmark, the exemplars of immorality.

Comment: Yes. It is sarcasm. I advise that you check the biography of the writer when you want to analyse the respective writer's work. Mark Twain's known to provide sarcastic statements. Good luck.

Comment: He has no more decency than a snake.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, it means that jays have fewer principles than a congressman, or an equal amount. Figuratively, it's a way of saying that congressmen have little in the way of principles. That's because the fact a jay has no more principles than a congressman is *illustrated by* the fact that:

> A jay will lie, a jay will steal, a jay will deceive... (etc.)

Because if a jay wouldn't do all those things, he would clearly have more principles than a congressman.